# Unity & C# Dev Kit solution not restored

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-devkit

I'm trying to run a simple script for unity

```
public class BirdScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * 10;
        }

    }
}
```

But VSC fails to restore the solution with this error

2023-12-16 10:46:02.365 [info] No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

2023-12-16 10:46:02.367 [info] Additional information of .NET SDKs for diagnostic
global.json file:
Not found

Host:
Version:      6.0.11
Architecture: x64
Commit:       943474ca16

.NET SDKs installed:
No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.11 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Download .NET:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info

2023-12-16 10:46:02.381 [info] Project system initialization finished. 0 project(s) are loaded, and 1 failed to load.

I've tried deleting all my extensions and re-installing them and also running the C# Dev Kit with Pre-Release version but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

I have SDK installed with where.exe dotnet showing me
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
(also deleted the x64 one)

Here it's visible that SDK is already installed
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.8
Found an existing package already installed. Trying to upgrade the installed package...

**Here is the solution that I did**

First i followed these steps from reddit

```
Uninstalled the Unity package named "Visual Studio Code Editor"

Installed the Unity package named "Visual Studio Editor"

Deleted all project filed (all the .csproj and .sln) from my project folder

Selected Visual Studio Code in the external programs in Unity the first two boxes was checked and clicked to regenerate project files.

Removed all the settings related to the C# and Unity extensions from VS Code

Uninstalled all versions of SDK from my computer (you might need to close VS Code and Unity).

Removed all the PATH windows environment variables related to dotnet

Uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled (I think you should look the version of Visual Studio related to your Unity version). I only installed two modules from Visual Studio: "Game development with Unity" and ".Net desktop development".

Restarted my computer and everything worked.
```

After that I did

```
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.8
```

After this the project loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have .NET SDK installed only a runtime. To solve this you need to do one of the following:

#### Winget

- Run this command:

```
winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.8
```

- Restart Visual Studio Code
- Try to run a simple C# project to test it

#### Visual Studio Installer

If you already have Visual Studio 2022 (yes, the classic one, not VS Code), you can modify its components which you can use from VS Code

- Find `Visual Studio Installer` in the Start Menu and open it
- Click `Modify` next to `Visual Studio Community 2022`
- At the top select `Individual Components`
- Search for `.NET SDK`
- Tick checkbox next to `.NET SDK`, for me it was the 9th option from the top because the search contains also other similary named items
- Click `Modify` in the bottom right corner
- Wait for the modification to complete
- Restart VS Code
- Try to run a simple C# project to test it

#### Visual Studio Installer (Alternative)

- Find `Visual Studio Installer` in the Start Menu and open it
- Click `Modify` next to `Visual Studio Community 2022`
- At the top select `Workloads`
- Find the category `Desktop & Mobile`, it should be 2nd from the top
- Tick checkbox next to `.NET desktop development`
- Click `Modify` in the bottom right corner
- Wait for the modification to complete
- Restart VS Code
- Try to run a simple C# project to test it